# Integrating Paypal with link in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, paypal

I want to integrate Paypal with wpf apps. Actually, in my wpf application there is a link of buying a product. So, when we click on that link i need to purchase that product through Paypal Integration and sending a mail to the user. Though, i have successfully done this in web application but dont know how to do this in wpf. can you plese help me?

Answer (score 1):

Check these following links up:

1. [integrating C# app with paypal](http://Integrating%20C#%20app%20with%20Paypal)
2. [PayPal-NET-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki)
3. [configuring Paypal-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Make-Your-First-Call)